# Which GUI element does iCal use for calendar view?

Tags: cocoa

I’m writing a simple iCal-like app in Cocoa that I’d like to resemble the main view of iCal.

Does anyone know which GUI element (i.e. NSWhatever) was used to create the Month-view (this thing: http://skitch.com/edwardog/b38ba/ical)?

Thanks!

PS – A hint at figuring this sort of thing out for myself would also be well appreciated; I’ve got a feeling that the answer lies somewhere in .nib, but after poking around I didn’t have much luck.

Comment: Edward, did you ever work out a Calendar view control (hopefully with events)?  I'd be interested in what you used for presenting modifiable events, etc.

Comment: @Byron nope. Sadly, the project didn’t really go anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CalendarWindow.nib, "Window".

Looks like it's all custom views I'm afraid.

Comment: Ah, that’s too bad, though I now see how exploring .nib files works.

I’ll give reproducing it a shot. Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 3):

The main calendar view must be a custom subclass of NSView, with custom drawing in the overridden drawRect: method.

If you really feel like poking around in running applications, check out [F-Script Anywhere](http://www.fscript.org/download/download.htm).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not claiming that iCal uses it, but you might try NSDatePicker, which supports a calendar style.